# What is a more useful title for this navigation bar? (contact/people synonyms)

Tags: terminology

We have a vertical navigation bar in our application with the following:

- Identity
- School
- Contact
- People
- Delete

This navigation bar appears on every profile. *Contact* is where users will find this person's address, email, and phone number. The *People* link is a new introduction in which users will find this person's emergency contacts. Most of the users in this application are underage, and therefore need an emergency contact who is (typically, but not always) the parents or other family. It can also include counsellors or other individuals.

User's are finding the *People* terminology difficult, as internally they have always referred to them as *Contacts*. I'd like to change the title to *Contacts*, but now I have no idea what to call the current *Contact* tab.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have restrictions on characters per line for that navigation, you have answered your own question 
First is *Contact information* and the second is *Emergency contact*

Alternatively you can use verbs like *Contact me* or well known phases like *SOS contact*

You should never use titles that could be understood in more than one way in the context of your interface.

Comment: this. also, since it's a vertical tab, you could simply wrap the label into 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

Contact -> About me

That till indicate that the user can find every info about her/himself there, such as info to her self such as name, picture, brief description, phone, email, IM and so on.

Don't forget to show your new menu to some of your students and ask them individually what they think they will find by clicking/taping on each menu item.

Comment: The student's themselves never see this page, but the administrative users do. I thought about just using _About_, but I thought that doesn't really provide any information from how it's different than _Identity_ and _School_ (the user's names/age/gender/school/grade/etc are found in those two tabs).

Comment: The _Contact_ tab only contains the information for contacting that student, like email/phone/address.

Comment: Ok, I understand. What about "Contact Maria" if Maria is the student's first name? The real problem here is that you separate info about the student from info about her parents.